# appendix currently giving me a blank page with just title - R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, landscape-portrait

I am trying to put a table in the first page of the appendix in R Markdown as per:

````
\newpage
# References {-}

<div id="refs"></div>

\newpage
# Appendix {-}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

```{r pre_table_appendix, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, fig.pos="H"}
tab <- matrix(c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4",
                "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4",
                "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4",
                "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('Variable','Variable','Variable','Variable')
rownames(tab) <- NULL
tab <- as.table(tab)

table_appendix <- kbl(tab, longtable = T, booktabs = T, row.names = 0, caption = "Title.") %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))

```

\begin{landscape}
```{r table_appendix_f, echo=FALSE}
table_appendix
```
\end{landscape}
````

However because my table_appendix is in landscape I end up with one blank page with just "Appendix" and then another page with the actual table. Anyone knows how to put the table together with Appendix?

Comment: Page with header ```Appendix``` should be in the portait mode or in the landscape too?

Comment: Thanks manro. The header Appendix should be in landscape because my first item in appendix is a table in landscape, if that makes sense. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: First page of Appendix(title + table) - landscape,  but other parts of the Appendix in the portait mode. Yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have right understand you...

Adding to our header:

```
 - \usepackage{pdflscape}
 - \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
 - \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

LaTeX-engine should be `pdflatex`.

Your code from the question:

````
\newpage
# References {-}

<div id="refs"></div>

\newpage
\blandscape
# Appendix {-}


\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

```{r pre_table_appendix, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE, fig.pos="H"}
library(kableExtra)
tab <- matrix(c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4",
                "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4",
                "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4",
                "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4"), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('Variable','Variable','Variable','Variable')
rownames(tab) <- NULL
tab <- as.table(tab)

table_appendix <- kbl(tab, longtable = T, booktabs = T, row.names = 0, caption = "Title.") %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))

```


```{r table_appendix_f, echo=FALSE}
table_appendix
```
\elandscape
\newpage

ccontent 
content
content
content
content
````

[image]

P.S. About this problem with the page's number, you know, I think.

---

**Without this problem:**

add to your header: `- \usepackage[paper=A4]{typearea}`

````
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=current}
\recalctypearea

# Appendix {-}

 *** your code***

```{r table_appendix_f, echo=FALSE}
table_appendix
```
     
\newpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,DIV=current}
\recalctypearea

ccontent 
content
````

And voila :)

[image]

**!!!** But remember, it has an influence to your margins. Check better before printing a document.

Comment: Thanks a lot @manro, once again works perfectly! Ya, the page's number is weird, is there any way to put it at the bottom?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues As I remember, with this package - no.  We should try something another. I'll check now. Wait...

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues I do it ;)

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues It is cool, i'm learning too into the process ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this! If you also want to take a look at this other question I asked in TeX, maybe you know:) - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621821/how-to-reduce-space-between-authors-via-header-includes

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues Sorry, it is yet complex for me.  But i'm always ready to help you here ;)